# Why transferring global window parameter if it's a global one

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have that basic `jQuery` script that use wrapper code, It initialized with the transfered global `window` parameter. Is it necessary transfering this parameter? `window` is a global parameter and you can use it from inside function if you transfer it or not.

What is the reason for that?

```
(function (window, undefined) {
    var jQuery = (function () {

        //Define a local copy of jQuery
        var jQuery = function (selector, context) {
            // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
            return new jQuery.fn.init(selector, context, rootjQuery);
        },  
    //some code
    //...
    //...
    //...

    window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
})(window);
```

Comment: Basically, what is said in the (very frequent) duplicates is that having a global variable enables the minification of its name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Smaller file size upon minification.

If you use `window` everywhere, the minifier will leave every reference as `window`. If you pass it through a closure, the minifier will convert it to something like `a`, which will save on the number of bytes if `window` was used more than once.

Comment: shouldn't the minification just remove the window completely ? I mean if you have `window.somevar = 2` and the minification does `a.somevar=2` (if a becomes a ref to window), doing `somevar=2` without a var is the same thing and smaller

Comment: @TheBrain, No,If the script is evaluated in strict mode it could complain that those global references are undefined if they happen to be undefined.